# probability of correctly distributing an item between undefined number of people with different preferences

Tags: probability

The assignment states there's a box of $2n$ items, $n$ from type $A$, and $n$ from type $B$. There are three groups of people, and one has to distribute the items between them.

Group 1 prefers type A and has a size of $a<n$; Group 2 prefers B and has a size of $b<n$; Group 3 has no preference and has a size of $2n-(a+b)$ [lets call this group $c$].

If the $2n$ items are distributed randomly between the $2n$ people, what is the probability of respecting everyone's preference?

As I see it, it would depend on the size of the groups and the order in which i distritube the items, so even if i distribute the items correctly, if the order changes, so does the probability. If, for example, I have $n=6$, $a=2$, $b=3$, and therefore $c=1$, $A=3$ and $B=3$, the probability would change depending on the order. When group $a$ picks first, then group $b$, and finally $c$, the result is 0.05. If the order changes and c picks first, then $a_1$,$b_1$,$a_2$,$b_2$, and $b_3$, then the probability would be 0.025.

Could you please help me see how should I get a general answer for this problem without substituting the variables for numbers?

Comment: Clearly, the answer depends on the size of the groups, but the order in which people pick makes no difference.

Comment: @dmalka: You made a numerical error for the case $c,a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,b_3$. If you work it out again, you should get $0.05$, not $0.025$. And as saulspatz notes, the order for the people shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we line the $2n$ people up in a row and hand them each a present at random. We can assume the people in group 1 come first, then those in group 2, and then those in group 3.  The presents they are handed give a string of $2n$ characters, $n$ A's and $n$ B's.  I'm sure you know how to compute the number of such strings.

The only acceptable strings start with $a$ A's followed by $b$ B's.  The remaining $2n-a-b$ characters comprise $n-a$ A's and $n-b$ B's.  Again, you know how to compute the number of acceptable strings.

The probability is the number of acceptable strings divided by the total number of strings.

Comment: I think I see it now, thanks!

Comment: Nice!${}{}{}{}{}$